# ICollection and decimal.Divide for Java

Tags: java, c#, double, icollection

I imported a program from Github. It is written in C# and I convert the codes to Java. Everything works except one, the method that needs ICollection and decimal.Divide.

Are there ICollection and decimal.Divide for Java? Or alternatives?

I opened Apache NetBeans and it shows:

```
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class ICollection
  location: class MathFormulas


cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable decimal
  location: class MathFormulas
```

Comment: What is `Double.Divide` for C#? =)

Comment: Java only has `Collection<T>`

Comment: @GuruStron sorry i mean decimal.Divide